# How do you supply custom reflections to a shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm using Unity with Amplify Shader Editor and/or Shader Graph, but willing to learn to write a shader if that's  what it takes to achieve what I need.

I need to be able to supply my own reflection instead of using global illumination (or maybe the answer is to somehow override or edit the global illumination?)

I have exactly the RGB values I need output by some nodes, and can plug it into the albedo or emission and see my reflections. The problem is that it's not ACTUALLY the reflections, and the shader ends up getting the actual reflections from the scene (skybox and reflection probes) and applies that on top of my custom reflection, so I see 2 different reflections at once. In addition, adjusting the roughness blurs/sharpens the actual reflection but not my custom reflection. How do I tell Unity to use my RGB info as the reflection so that it can be affected by roughness so I can make the reflections look soft or clear as I want?