# How do you recreate a standard lit shader using custom lighting?

Tags: unity, shaders

When using a standard lit shader the environment reflection on the material gets soft/blurry when you have smoothness at anything lower than 1 (which would be perfect mirror reflection). But when you make a shader that uses custom lighting, you have to manually provide the reflection and lose the metalic and smoothness parameters. How do you recreate the same functionality and appearance of a standard lit shader in a custom lighting shader?

Comment: This looks like a slightly different angle on solving the same fundamental game development challenge described in [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/208621/39518). Instead of posting a new question, want to edit your previous one to clarify/elaborate, and open up this angle for answers there? Constructive edits bump a question in the feed just like a new post, without leaving a clutter of dead ends for future searches.

Comment: We can't answer this question unless you clarify whether your custom shader is a Surface shader or a Vertex/Fragment shader.

Comment: Have you looked inside standard lit shader files to see how its accomplished there?